# VSCode support for Java Unnamed Packages

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm a teacher with a lot of simple .java files to grade. The students have not and will not be using packages as this is a rather simple class.

Having one .java file runs fine. When a second one or more are added, VSCode compiles all the files in the folder. Needless to say, some student files may contain syntax errors. So I can't run or debug the one student file I'm grading.

Is there a workaround for this situation? It seems to be an option under Java specification.

---

7.4.2. Unnamed Packages states:

An implementation of the Java SE Platform must support at least one unnamed package. An implementation may support more than one unnamed package, but is not required to do so. Which ordinary compilation units are in each unnamed package is determined by the host system.

Comment: if its multiple .java file within a folder, right click on that particular .java file > click on 'run as'

Comment: make a folder for each student?

Comment: Creating a folder for students would be a pain. Since students don't use the PACKAGE statement, why should VSCode assume all files need to be compliled.

Comment: As to FILE -> RUN AS, that would work in Explorer but not in VSCODE. Explorer would run it with java.exe. I want to be able trace and debug student code in VSCode to provide the best possible feedback on their coding skills.

Comment: As an option, you can build and run it in terminal by run `javac hello.java` and `java hello`

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try on `Code Runner`. Then you can right-click and select `Run Code` or click the `Run Code` button on the top-right.

**Update:**

In fact, you can ignore the `Build failed` prompt and click `Proceed` to continue the `Run Java` or `Debug Java` actions.

Comment: Code Runner will indeed run just the one file.

Comment: However, in many cases, I need to use the Java Debug functionality to trace student code to provide great feedback for improvement. Correct output is insufficient.

Comment: I had one student hardcode just the correct output. That was it -- just a PRINTLN.

Comment: @TOMC haha, that's interesting and very sorry for my delay, could you have a look at the update of this answer?